# What's the fastest way of finding the index of the maximum value in an array?

Tags: arrays, rust

I have a 2D array of type `f32` (from `ndarray::ArrayView2`) and I want to find the index of the maximum value in each row, and put the index value into another array.

The equivalent in Python is something like:

```py
import numpy as np

for i in range (0, max_val, batch_size):
   sims = xp.dot(batch, vectors.T) 
   # sims is the dot product of batch and vectors.T
   # the shape is, for example, (1024, 10000)

   best_rows[i: i+batch_size] = sims.argmax(axis = 1)
```

In Python, the function `.argmax` is very fast, but I don't see any function like that in Rust. What's the fastest way of doing so?

Comment: Is it actually an array or is it a `Vec`?

Comment: You're going to need to show some Rust code for context here.

Comment: @jhpratt It is, as mentioned in the question, an array.

Comment: Yes, but lots of times people will say array when they are actually using a vector. Your clarification with the addition of the actual type is helpful, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [approach from @David A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57815298/155423) is cool, but as mentioned, there's a catch: `f32` & `f64` do not implement `Ord::cmp`. (Which is really a pain in your-know-where.)

There are multiple ways of solving that: You can implement `cmp` yourself, or you can use `ordered-float`, etc..

In my case, this is a part of a bigger project and we are very careful about using external packages. Besides, I am pretty sure we don't have any `NaN` values. Therefore I would prefer using `fold`, which, if you take a close look at the `max_by_key` source code, is what they have been using too.

```
for (i, row) in matrix.axis_iter(Axis(1)).enumerate() {
    let (max_idx, max_val) =
        row.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .fold((0, row[0]), |(idx_max, val_max), (idx, val)| {
                if &val_max > val {
                    (idx_max, val_max)
                } else {
                    (idx, *val)
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider the easy case of a general `Ord` type: The answer will differ slightly depending on whether you know the values are `Copy` or not, but here's the code:

```rust
fn position_max_copy<T: Ord + Copy>(slice: &[T]) -> Option<usize> {
    slice.iter().enumerate().max_by_key(|(_, &value)| value).map(|(idx, _)| idx)
}

fn position_max<T: Ord>(slice: &[T]) -> Option<usize> {
    slice.iter().enumerate().max_by(|(_, value0), (_, value1)| value0.cmp(value1)).map(|(idx, _)| idx)
}
```

The basic idea is that we pair [a reference to] each item in the array (really, a slice - it doesn't matter if it's a Vec or an array or something more exotic) with its index, use `std::iter::Iterator` functions to find the maximum value according to the value only (not the index), then return just the index. If the slice is empty `None` will be returned. Per the documentation, the rightmost index will be returned; if you need the leftmost, do `rev()` *after* `enumerate()`.

`rev()`, `enumerate()`, `max_by_key()`, and `max_by()` are documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html); `slice::iter()` is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) (but that one needs to be on your shortlist of things to recall without documentation as a rust dev); `map` is `Option::map()` documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) (ditto). Oh, and `cmp` is `Ord::cmp` but most of the time you can use the `Copy` version which doesn't need it (e.g. if you're comparing integers).

---

Now here's the catch: `f32` isn't `Ord` because of the way IEEE floats work. Most languages ignore this and have subtly wrong algorithms. The most popular crate to provide a total order on `Ord` (by declaring all NaN to be equal, and greater than all numbers) seems to be [ordered-float](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/1.0.2/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html). Assuming it's implemented correctly it should be very very lightweight. It does pull in `num_traits` but this is part of the most popular numerics library so might well be pulled in by other dependencies already.

You'd use it in this case by mapping `ordered_float::OrderedFloat` (the "constructor" of the tuple type) over the slice iter (`slice.iter().map(ordered_float::OrderedFloat)`). Since you only want the position of the maximum element, no need to extract the f32 afterward.

Comment: Note that this is for a 1D vector, but the OP is using a 2D array, so he will need to iterate over the rows of his array and call `position_max` for each row.

Comment: For the one-dimensional case, another option is `(0..slice.len()).max_by_key(|i| &slice[i])`. (I did not test this, but it should work regardless of whether `T: Copy`.)

Comment: Yes, that's probably easier to understand TBH. The issue with `max_by_key` for `T: !Copy` is that it (implicitly) requires the return type to be `Ord + 'static`; I'm not sure if that's actually necessary for the algorithm or maybe an oversight.